# How should I debug the dev and prod version of an Azure Function?

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, azure-functions

I'm a beginner at using azure functions and I'm a bit confused about the best way to store configuration for the different environments.
When creating asp.net apps I've been using three appsettings files; appsettings.json, appsetting.development.json and appsettings.production.json. The file was chosen based on the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT parameter in the launch settings files.
The appsetting files have references to different databases and other services depending on which environment I'm running. This allows me to easily debug the application when it's running against production servers.

In an azure function I understand you should use local.settings.json for the local settings. The settings for other environments like prod and staging should be set using the Configuration section on azure. But doing this I no longer have the ability to debug against for example the production database.
Is there a recommended way to do this for azure functions.
I have tried to figure out if I could still use appsettings for azure functions but I can't really understand if this is possible or not.

So my question is, what is the recommended way to debug an azure function running in the production environment? Is it possible?

Comment: You shouldn't really be debugging against production anyway

Comment: Is that a general rule? A couple of times that has helped me to solve complicated bugs that only occurred in the production environment. How would you solve an issue that happens in prod but not in any other environment?

Comment: I haven't debugged against a prod database for years. These days we use logs, diagnostics, audit trails etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable remote debugging the Configuration section of your function apps, there are many examples on how to do this, [here is one example](https://markheath.net/post/remote-debugging-azure-functions)

For the configurations use App Configuration Store with a label for each of your environments the documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/overview)